Is it possible to detect AR planes from 3D objects that we create in unity?
I know AR Foundation detects planes from the real physical environment but I was wondering if it was possible to detect AR planes from 3D objects that we create in the Unity Editor. For instance, I have a table that I made in the Unity Editor, is it possible to detect planes of the surface of this table?
I tried reading online and the documentation but I don't see anything mentioned about it so far.

Unity XR Simulation can do it in the Unity Editor.
You can learn its code in Packages folder (of Project window).
